# Gsub returning final match rather than first.

Tags: r, gsub

I have a string

```
S="a, Hello. The, c."
```

I want "Hello" returned.

I thought this would work but it doesn't.

```
sub(".*\\,\\ |\\..*","",S)
```

Comment: on what basis is `Hello` returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (multiple `sub` calls instead of `|`):

```
sub("\\..*\\.","", sub("[^,]*\\,\\ ","",S)) # first remove the chars before Hello, then after Hello
# [1] "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` to return the word

```
gsub("^\\S+\\s+|\\..*", "", S)
#[1] "Hello"
```